# Proving that $pr$ and $qs$ are perpendicular

Tags: geometry

Consider a convex quadrilateral with vertices at $a, b, c$ and $d$ and on each side draw a square lying outside the given quadrilateral, as in the picture below. Let $p, q, r$ and $s$ be the centers of those squares:[image]

Prove that the line segment between $p$ and $r$ is perpendicular and equal in length to the line segment between $q$ and $s$.

---

So far I have established that \begin{align*}
p &= \frac{a + b + (a-b)i}{2} \\
q &= \frac{b+c + (b-c)i}{2} \\
r &= \frac{c + d + (c-d)i}{2} \\
s &= \frac{a + d + (d-a)i}{2}\, .
\end{align*}
From here I want to prove that $p - r = q-s.$ However, when I substitute, I get $$\frac{(a + b - c - d) + (a + d - b - c)i}{2} = \frac{(b + c - a - d) + (b + a - c - d)i}{2},$$ which I can't seem to manipulate to get a equality. I know where to go from here by simply rotating point $p$ to $q$ and $r$ to $s,$ but could someone help me on the part I'm currently stuck on?

Comment: That's [van Aubel's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Aubel%27s_theorem).

Comment: In the above there is an external link to a proof by Nishiyama.

Comment: You're missing an $\mathbf i$: $$(p-r)=\pm(q-s)i$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are actually done.

What you have in effect

is that $z_1 = [R + iS]$

and $z_2 = [S - iR]$

Two things are therefore immediate.

$|z_1| = |z_2|.$

The *slope* of $z_1$ is the negative reciprocal of the
*slope* of $z_2$.

This means the $z_1$ and $z_2$ are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: Wait, that's true! Thanks so much!